# Cant find footer links in Magento

Tags: magento, footer

I am trying to change the links in the footer of a Magento page.

In the footer there is the following HTML:

```
<div class="col1 gapRight floatLeft">
    <h2>Customer Service</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.php/about-magento-demo-store">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.php/customer-service">Customer Service</a></li>
        <li class="last privacy"><a href="/index.php/privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li class="last privacy"><a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="links">
        <li class="first" ><a href="/index.php/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/" title="Site Map" >Site Map</a></li>
        <li ><a href="/index.php/catalogsearch/term/popular/" title="Search Terms" >Search Terms</a></li>
        <li ><a href="/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/" title="Advanced Search" >Advanced Search</a></li>
        <li ><a href="/index.php/sales/guest/form/" title="Orders and Returns" >Orders and Returns</a></li>
        <li class=" last" ><a href="/index.php/contacts/" title="Contact Us" >Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The first `ul` list is defined as a CMS Static Block called `footer_links`.

Can anyone tell me where I can find the second `ul` list?

Ive googled about and I keep getting reffered back to the Static Blocks. This second `ul` list is definitely not a Static Block (Ive gone as far as removing all the static blocks and this list is still there). Where else could it be defined?

Comment: Is there something relevant in  app/design/frontend/yourtemplate/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml or in app/design/frontend/yourtemplate/default/layout/local.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is using the core footer links, stored in XML files.

Open your Magento folder, go to app/design/frontend/. When you are in your template folder open the Layout folder. You may need to create and overwrite if they don't exist.

**Site Map**

In catalog.xml file:

```
 <reference name="footer_links">
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map">
         <label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" />
         <title>Site Map</title>
     </action>
 </reference><br>
```

**Search Terms and Advanced Search**

In catalogsearch.xml:

```
 <reference name="footer_links">
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms">
         <label>Search Terms</label><url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" />
         <title>Search Terms</title>
     </action>

    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch">
         <label>Advanced Search</label>
         <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" />
         <title>Advanced Search</title>
     </action>
 </reference>
```

**Contact Us**

In contacts.xml file:

```
 <reference name="footer_links">
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="contacts" ifconfig="contacts/contacts/enabled">
         <label>Contact Us</label>
         <url>contacts</url>
         <title>Contact Us</title>
         <prepare>true</prepare>
     </action>
 </reference>
```